# In C#, difference between two dates, considers only the date (dd) and not the complete date including month and year

Tags: c#, date, datetime, difference, days

Following is my program, where I'm trying to calculate the difference between 2 dates, but the result shows up the number of days, considering only the date and not the month or year. Basically I tried two dates "01-01-2017" and "10-10-2017", which is bringing out 9.00625. Can you please help?

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String lType;
        DateTime cDate = DateTime.ParseExact("01-01-2017", "dd-mm-yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        double eDays;
        String response;

        do
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the license type :");
        lType = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the expiry date :");
       DateTime eDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd-mm-yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
       eDays = (eDate - cDate).TotalDays;
       Console.WriteLine(eDays);
            if(eDays <= 15)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} expires within 15 days.", lType);
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue ?(yes/no) :");
                response = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue ?(yes/no) :");
            response = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        while (response == "yes");

    }
}
```

Comment: what was the expected output?

Comment: mm is minutes, not months, use MM instead

Comment: Why are you parsing strings for dates, why not use the constructor designed for it, as `new DateTime(2017,1,1)` ?

Comment: To remove a portion of a day and move to the start of the day at mignight use the Date property. eDays = (eDate.Date - cDate.Date).TotalDays;

Comment: Expected output is the number of days, for example difference between 01-01-2017 and 10-10-2017 is 282, but the program is considering only the date and showing up 9 and I'm not sure why is there a decimal.

Comment: changing mm to MM did work, thanks vc :)

Comment: Be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and don't duplicate code like "Do you want to continue" / `response =`... - think about how to do that once.

Answer (score 0):

**May be this helpful :**

You are trying to get number of number of days difference, in your case, you used double, so it has double. If you want to get as full details like days, hours etc. Then try following :

```
TimeSpan baseTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(1, 12, 15, 16);
      // Create an array of timespan intervals.
      TimeSpan[] intervals = { TimeSpan.FromDays(1.5), 
                               TimeSpan.FromHours(1.5), 
                               TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45), 
                               TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(505),
                               new TimeSpan(1, 17, 32, 20), 
                               new TimeSpan(-8, 30, 0) };
      // Calculate a new time interval by adding each element to the base interval.
      foreach (var interval in intervals)
         Console.WriteLine(@"{0,-10:g} - {3}{1,15:%d\:hh\:mm\:ss\.ffff} = {4}{2:%d\:hh\:mm\:ss\.ffff}",
                           baseTimeSpan, interval, baseTimeSpan.Subtract(interval),
                           interval < TimeSpan.Zero ? "-" : "",
                           baseTimeSpan < interval.Duration() ? "-" : "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the difference as double you could save it as TimeSpan and compare it with a new TimeSpan with a duration of 15days.

```
TimeSpan eDays = (eDate - cDate); 
TimeSpan compareValue = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0, 0);

if(eDays <= compareValue){
    ...
}
```

Or another possible way:

```
if(eDate > cDate.AddDays(15)){
    ...
}
```